# Error in Postion Report (FIX 4.4): Group 702's first entry does not start with delimiter 704

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj, quickfixn

I am new to the FIX protocol and I am using QuickFIX to parse my FIX messages. Whenever I receive a Position Report message (`AP`), it gets rejected by the FIX engine with the below error:

> Group 702's first entry does not start with delimiter 704

Here `702` is a group tag. I did some research and found that a repeating group message uses its first field as a delimiter. In my case group `702` is  supposed to have either tag `704` (LongQty) or `705` (ShortQty). Only one of either tags will be present.

My counterparty is not sending the `703` tag. When the FIX engine sees there is no `704` tag in some cases, it rejects the message. Please let me know your suggestion to over come this problem.

Answer (score 2):

FIX expects every group to start with a single consistent tag.

You can alter that tag in your XML DataDictionary, for instance, to use 704 instead of 703, by rearranging (or deleting/adding) the fields in that group.

> In my case group 702 is supposed to have either tag 704(LongQty) or 705(ShortQty).

**No, that won't work.**  Does it always start with 704 or does it always start with 705?  It can't be one-of-either.

If your counterparty really is saying that it's one-of-either, then they are doing FIX wrong and we should publicly shame them.  (Seriously, can't they just put 704=0 instead of omitting it?)  To deal with this idiocy, you may have to hack the QF engine.

I suggest you double-check with your counterparty to confirm that they really are doing it wrong like this.  I'm hoping (for your sake) that you are mistaken.

**EDIT:**

This is from the FIX 44 spec, Vol 1, page 19:

> If the repeating group is used, the first field of the repeating group is required. This allows implementations of the protocol to use the first field as a "delimiter" indicating a new repeating group entry. The first field listed after the NoXXX, then becomes conditionally required if the NoXXX field is greater than zero.

Comment: I double checked with my data dictionary, my counterparty is expecting either of the two tags. please look at the below message                                                                                          _20161004-18:20:15.063 : 8=FIX.4.49=23735=AP34=549=XXXX52=20161004-18:20:14.83556=XXXDEMOFIX1=9277455=GBPUSD231=1581=1702=1705=27200710=XXXX715=20161004721=981a4eec-1886-4571-bd25-cf3c9e10115a728=0730=1.27940472230385731=1734=1.2794047223038510=198_

Comment: You mean the counterparty is *sending* (not ~expecting~) either of the two tags, right?  You are the receiver.

Comment: Yes. That's right. Is there any way to over come this.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  You'll have to hack the engine.  You should also inform them that they are using FIX wrong; maybe they'll decide to fix it.  Looks like this is spelled out in FIX protocol spec volume 1; you should find the passage (it's not a hard spec to read) in the spec for the relevant FIX version (4.4, 5.0, whatever) and pass it on to your counterparty.

Comment: I'm probably mistaken, but I'm seeing in the message the OP posted in comment 702 followed by 705. 703 is conditionally required if 702>1 (which it is not). Then either 704 or 705 should follow (they are both marked optional in [the definition I'm seeing](http://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/compBlock_PositionQty.html))

Comment: @TT - That conditionally-required annotation for 703 is in conflict with the general FIX-spec requirement that groups must start with a consistent delimiter.  I can only assume that the 703 annotation must be an error.  If I was implementing the standard FIX DD, I would treat 703 as required.

Comment: @TT - See spec excerpt I added to my answer above.

Comment: I generally get the impression that Vivek's counterparty might be somewhat new to FIX, and is using a custom-created solution rather than a proven engine.  Lacking experience in FIX and existing engines, they don't realize that repeating groups can be a minefield, and have unknowingly diverted from best practice.